# GLSurfaceView with opengl ES 3.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

my question is : is GLSurfaceView support EGL context 3.0 for api18+.
because i used setEGLContextClientVersion( 3 ) then crash accurs , i didn't tried it only with one device which has android 4.4.2 
and the manifest contains

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: Does the device support ES 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) states, the device may not support OpenGL 3.0, so you should check that before setting the egl context version.

However, if you state `required=true` for the `uses-feature` in your manifest, once the App is published in Google Play Store, it shouldn't be visible for those devices that don't support it. So they won't be able to install it unless they manage to download the APK from another source.

To check if 3.0 is available you can do the following:

```
private static double glVersion = 3.0;

private static class ContextFactory implements GLSurfaceView.EGLContextFactory {

     private static int EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION = 0x3098;

     public EGLContext createContext(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
          Log.w(TAG, "creating OpenGL ES " + glVersion + " context");
          int[] attrib_list = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, (int) glVersion, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
          // attempt to create a OpenGL ES 3.0 context
          EGLContext context = egl.eglCreateContext(display, eglConfig, EGL10.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attrib_list);
          return context; // returns null if 3.0 is not supported;
     }
}
```